# Unable to flash arduino pro micro from Terminal

Tags: avrdude, arduino-pro-micro, atmega32u4

I am trying to upload an hex file to my arduino pro micro using Avrdude . The thing is that I cannot upload any code using the Avrdude terminal commands , but when I use arduino IDE to upload any code it perfectly uploads the code to Arduino.

**The command I am using on the terminal:**

```
avrdude -C C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf -v -V -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM15 -b57600 -D -U flash:w:C:\Users\santi\Documents\keyboard\corne\crkbd_rev1_layout_split_3x6_3_mine.hex:i
```

I already have avrdude on the environment variables on my windows 10 machine.

**Output**:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM15
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I keep waiting but it does not upload the code.

I added a push button for RST and GND pins to enter bootloader mode, and I am pressing the reset button. I even tried resetting twice quickly, but I get the same result.

I tried using the Arduino and the code gets uploaded.

I uploaded the following code:

```
int RXLED = 17; 
void setup(){
  pinMode(RXLED, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(RXLED, LOW);
  delay(1500); 
  digitalWrite(RXLED, HIGH);   
  delay(1500); 
}
```

The command ran in the IDE is:

```
"C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -V -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM16 -b57600 -D "-Uflash:w:C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-F0563C64AD4C1F392D3E71AA32E4F874/blink_nano.ino.hex:i"
```

Arduino IDE output:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM16
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .
Found programmer: Id = "CATERIN"; type = S
    Software Version = 1.0; No Hardware Version given.
Programmer supports auto addr increment.
Programmer supports buffered memory access with buffersize=128 bytes.

Programmer supports the following devices:
    Device code: 0x44

avrdude: devcode selected: 0x44
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9587 (probably m32u4)
avrdude: reading input file "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-F0563C64AD4C1F392D3E71AA32E4F874/blink_nano.ino.hex"
avrdude: writing flash (3852 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 0.29s

avrdude: 3852 bytes of flash written

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I tried using the same Avrdude command in the terminal.

```
"C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/bin/avrdude" "-CC:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf" -v -V -patmega32u4 -cavr109 -PCOM16 -b57600 -D "-Uflash:w:C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino-sketch-F0563C64AD4C1F392D3E71AA32E4F874/blink_nano.ino.hex:i"
```

**Output:**

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM16
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\\.\COM16": El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
```

I don´t know why it uses a different port.
I tried changing the port in that command but I get the same result as before

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Users\santi\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avrdude\6.3.0-arduino17/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM15
         Using Programmer              : avr109
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
         AVR Part                      : ATmega32U4
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    20     4    0 no       1024    4      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65     6   128    0 yes     32768  128    256  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : butterfly
         Description     : Atmel AppNote AVR109 Boot Loader

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

I could just use the arduino IDE to flash my device but the problem is that I only have the hex file. I am trying to flash my device with a hex file from [QMK Configurator](https://config.qmk.fm/). I am trying to build a custom keyboard.

Comment: When you tried the same command as the IDE, did you close the IDE? There is a possibility that it has the port open, which will block other programs from accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset the Arduino using a very special procedure in order
for it to accept being programmed. This involves opening the port at
1200 bps, toggling some control lines, and closing the port again.
You may try using this [ard-reset-arduino](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/master/bin/ard-reset-arduino) Python script with the
option `--caterina`.

By the way, this script belongs a project called “Arduino-Makefile”. You
may want to take a look if you want to program your Arduino from the
command line. Alternatively, you can use [arduino-cli](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/).

Comment: *"I am trying to flash my device with a hex file from QMK Configurator."* The arduino-cli does the 1200baud touch as part of the upload process, but it might not apply or may need clarification on how to apply. I'm not sure how you'd make use of it unless it has the ability to be supplied arbitrary hex files to upload, or has a stand-alone command for issuing a 1200 baud touch, or unless you can sneak your hex file over top of one the compile command had created.  *"I even tried resetting twice quickly"* This should have given them 8 seconds of bootloader time, though the tool would help.